# How to configure java bytecode output path in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, build

I'm just starting using VSCode for java development. My Operating System is windows 10, and I have installed the `Java Extension Pack` extensions. My toy java project `JavaTest` works fine. But I found that the bytecodes built from sources were stored in `JAVA DEPENDENCIES` like the picture below:
[image]

And I found the real storage folder is `C:\\Users\\${username}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\workspaceStorage\\..\\redhat.java\\jdt_ws\\JavaTest_366de67d`.

I prefer the bytecodes stored in a folder inside the project root directory like the eclipse's `bin` directory. Can I make some configuration to get it?

Any reply will be appreciated!